# How to override the one css file with another css file

Tags: css

My parent page is using `custom1.css` and child page is using `custom2.css`. My issue is child page css properties are override by parent page css. How can I block parent page css acting on the child page elemenets.

Comment: Can you share an example for this? It will make it more easy to understand.

Comment: The last CSS rules that get processed define what happens, you should check the loading order. Besides that, it would be more elegant to give your child elements an own class.

Answer (score 1):

CSS styles are apply as the order those are in. Check this example, first style override by the second and final width of div will be 40px.

```
div{
 width:300px;
}

div{
 width:40px;
}
```

linking style sheets also the same.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style_2.css">
```

Here `style_2.css` override the same styles in `style_1.css` because it links secondly.

**So what you have to do is, style sheet you need to apply link lastly.**

Answer (score 0):

> How can i block parent page css acting on the child page elemenets?

By removing the `custom1.css` reference from the `<head>` of the child page.

If, for some reason, you cannot do that, then you need to read about css specificity in order to understand how the "parent css" is overriding rules in the "child css".

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

Css is applied using levels.

So just adding a container around everything shoudl prevent it

You can do:
.class1 #content{ make it blue here }

.class2 #content{ make it red here }

Doing it by file is not possible.
You should make sure that never happends, this can yield unexpected results

Answer (score 0):

You could either add   `!important;` after your css styles (which is a bad example) or you could make some more specific selectors.

```
body div#main{
  /* Style */
}
```

The above is more specific and will "win" over the following:

```
div#main{
  /* Style */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On you your child page please check that you CSS order should be in correct way if you are using both CSS files

```
<html> 
<head>
    <title>Page title</title>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="custom2.css">
</head>
```

so that cascading will work in correct way as per your expectation

also there are other things that you need to check like CSS Specificity, Inheritance, and the Cascade. You may like to check http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/ this

Hope it helps!